# Diffeomorphism from $T M$ to $M \times \mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism, tangent-bundle

Let $M$ be a two-dimensional manifold. Suppose there are two vector fields on $M$, $X(p) = (p,V (p))$ and $Y (p) = (p,W (p))$, such that
$$\text{span}\{V (p),W (p)\} = T_p M$$
for all $p \in  M$.
Construct a diffeomorphism from $T M$ to $M \times \mathbb{R}^2$.

Here is what I know so far:

Since $\text{span}\{V (p),W (p)\}$ span $T_p M$, then there is a diffeomorphism. Since

- $T_pM=\cup_{p\in M} T_p M$
- $M\times \mathbb{R}^2=\cup_{p\in M} \{p \} \times \mathbb{R}^2$

We need to find an isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $T_p M$ for all $p \in M$. But I still cannot find it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "Since span{V(p),W(p)} span TpM, then there is a diffeomorphism." I don't understand what this sentence means. Also, we don't need an isomorphism "from $M\times\mathbb{R}^2$ to $T_pM$ for all $p\in M$", we need one from $M\times\mathbb{R}^2$ to $TM$. In fact, you can construct a bundle map that does this: think about how to construct an isomorphism between $T_pM$ and $\{p\}\times\mathbb{R}^2$ for all $p\in M$ in some consistent manner.

Comment: Sorry, I meant from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $T_p M$. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM$, since $\{X(p),Y(p)\}$ is a basis of $T_pM$, there exist unique real coefficients $a_p(v),b_p(v)$ such that $v=a_p(v)X(p)+b_p(v)Y(p)$. Now, it can be seen that $a,b\colon TM\to\mathbf{R}$ are smooth, since $X$ and $Y$ are, then $$TM\ni(p,v)\mapsto(p,a_p(v),b_p(v))\in M\times\mathbf{R}^2,$$
is the required diffeomorphism, whose inverse is given by $(p,x,y)\mapsto(p,xX(p)+yY(p))$.

Comment: One slight problem: the hypothesis of the question is only that $X(p),Y(p)$ span $T_p M$; so one must also derive that $X(p),Y(p)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: $\{X(p),Y(p)\}$ must be a basis of $T_pM$, since it is a generating family having two elements of a two-dimensional space ($M$ being a surface). I have the bad habit to leave unsolved the linear algebra matters.

Comment: Thank you so much!